# Using Div tags with a href as placeholders for clickable menu elements

Tags: css, html, audio, href

I have a number of divs covering a different portions of a menu on a background image on a webpage.

Within the div I hav an a href to link to another page a play a click sound

I've used a CSS trick to fill the div so that the cursor changes right across the div. See the code below

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function playSound(soundfile) {
      "<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
  }
</script>     

<div id="apWelcome">
   <a href= "#" class="fill-div" onclick="playSound('Sounds/click.ogg');"> </a>
</div>
```

The CSS for apWelcome and to fill out the area is listed below:

```
#apWelcome {
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
left: 104px;
top: 216px;
width: 49px;
height: 66px;
}

a.fill-div {
cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The problem is that in FF24 the click behaviour is fine but nor sound, Chrome - half-works (sound plays)- visually the page jumps down, IE does not display cursor or has no functionality.

Anyone know a workaround for this for all three browswers or a completely different method. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/soundlink.shtml#current) article about sounds in html (cross browser).
the different browsers allows differnent types of sounds files.

also, you dont have to use your `div` as placeHolder for the `a` tag, you can directly call your function from the `div`'s `onclick` (with `cursor:poiner;` you wont notice any difference)

See this Fiddle, a complete solution: http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/ybxBq/

Comment: Thank you, I've followed the instructions and see that different browswers use different audio file formats. I fixed this up using the link you provided. I've ended up with                       <div id="apWelcome" class="fill-div"                                                    onclick="clicksound.playclip()">                                           <a href= "www.google.com"></a>
</div>                                                              I'm still not getting a sound to play. It recognises the cursor over the div but no click action. I'm missing something silly I bet.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much for this. Exactly what I wanted. Am I able to nav to another age using the same onclick?

Comment: for an even better solution, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/ybxBq/2/

Comment: This works perfectly in chrome and firefox but in ie it won't fire. Here is the website http://pcrepairdirect.com/Aideen/index.html. In the CSS I have the div positioned absolutely which seems to cause the issue for IE

Comment: something is messed up with your HTML. [this](http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/6209/p3e1.jpg) is what I see in firefox. in explorer it doesnt render at all. fix the markup-problem in the code. and then it will work on all browsers.

Comment: Also the a href seems to work in Chrome but not in Firefox. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes I see the issue, the div needs to be positioned over the correct element on the page. The code works od all three browsers it;s just puttung the div after the content of the page. See the outcome here http://pcrepairdirect.com/Aideen/index.html   If i try and position it I lose functionality. Again thanks for any help you can give me on this.

Comment: its hard to correct the problem from here, I need to see the code itself. but for the absolute positioning: give this CSS to **#apWelcome** position: absolute; cursor:pointer; top:220px; left: 125px; width: 20px; height: 70px;

Comment: That has worked. Except in IE it only allows the outer line to be clicked and not the middle section and in IE the link doesn't work. It's so close now. Does IE need to have a transparent fill maybe?

Comment: no. the problem is elsewhere. because as you can see.. my fiddle works on IE also. so the same technique should work here. this requires more investigation. and possibly rethinking of the entire layout.

Comment: Yes I see that. Maybe do you want the html and css file I am working off?

Comment: Thanks you i'm new to this forum. Will I put a rar on box.com and share the link with you? Thanks for the patience and help. Really appreciated.

Comment: yes do it that way, because I dont see private inbox in the forum.

Comment: Here is the link to the rar. It contains the index.html and styles.css as well as the background image on the main page. Thanks for all the help https://app.box.com/s/w5rlnfrpj20tc6iren02

Comment: check out my new answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've rebuilt the entire layout from scratch.
you can download it from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lpyd5fe1aqo338z/CompleteHTML.zip) (I will keep the link alive for a week)
I dont know if it was necessary, but.. it was easier for me.

1. I'm using an `img` in BackgroundContainer and not CSS `background`, that way: if someone prints the page, he still sees the background.
2. I'm using fixed `height`&`width` for the 'Site', but all of its content is in %. so it should scale beautifully if the size of the site change.
3. for testing in IE, you have to run the HTML from a server (and not from the local file) - so the browser wont stop the script
4. I've deleted almost all your scripts, so put them back (one by one, each time make sure the page is still working in all browsers)
5. NOTICE that I've change some of your classes & files name, so check your scripts and CSS's accordingly (also, I rearranged the Image folder).
6. tested on IE10, FF, Chrome
7. notice the url(dummy) as background-image for the clickable elements.

good luck.